# Hide a radio button visibility once it is clicked for the whole project in C# for a Windows Phone 8 application

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, navigation, radio-button

I have code as :

```
           if (rb1.IsChecked.Value)
            {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/enterque.xaml?chkd=" + rb1.IsChecked, 
            UriKind.Relative));
            this.rb1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;               
            }
```

When `rb1` is checked it collapse its visibility on coming back to this page. But When I navigate to same page again via MainPage it is again visible ??

Is `rb1.visibility` is having only local scope ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take one `Visibility` Variable in `App.xaml.cs` file n it would hold the `value` for state for `Visibility` IN Application.

Declaration:

```
public static Visibility radVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Use:

```
rb1.Visibility = App.radVisibility;
```

Declare it in `App.xaml.cs`

```
public static Visibility radVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

MainPage.cs:

```
if (rb1.IsChecked.Value)
{
    App.radVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;               
    this.rb1.Visibility = App.radVisibility;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/enterque.xaml?chkd=" + rb1.IsChecked,UriKind.Relative));
}


protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    this.rb1.Visibility = App.radVisibility;
}
```

Comment: it is working same as  this.rb1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;   I need radiobutton should be disabled once it is clicked in the project. The problem with rb1.visibility = app.radvisibility is that once i comes to same page where radiobuttons are placed via "BACK" button it is visible.

Comment: you would also need to set value of radiobutton at onNavigatedTo as it is static so you can hold it in whole application

Comment: i am not able to do it, can you please help with the code.

Comment: now the new issue arised... rb1 is collapsed once the app starts... #serious_trouble

Comment: It should not be. but you can set radVisibility = Visibility.Visible; in Constructor for the Application object that is App(){radVisibility = Visibility.Visible;}, Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should use listener event, once radio button click, you need to handle clicked event
and then hide the radio button.

Hope following link may helpful.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codenameone-discussions/WSRld91pSas